# Find all solutions of $2^{m}-3^{n}=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

> Find all pairs of natural numbers (m,n) satisfying  $2^{m}-3^{n}=1$

My attempt:
      $$2^{m}-3^{n}=1$$
$\implies 2^m\equiv 1 \pmod3$
$\implies m=2k$  for some integer $k$.
Hence, $$((2^{k})^{2}-1)=3^{n}$$
This implies,
     $$(2^k-1)(2^k+1)=3^n$$
But, $(2^k-1,2^k+1)=1$ , this implies that one among $2^k-1$ and $2^k+1$ is equal to $1$.
It is obvious that $2^k-1<2^k+1$.Therefore, $2^k-1=1$ and $k=1$.
This gives, $m=2$ and $n=1$.$(m,n)=(2,1)$ is the only solution of $2^{m}-3^{n}=1$.Does this look alright? Are there any other solutions besides $(2,1)$. Also, does my solution look neat(I don't think it does)?

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69253/are-there-any-solutions-to-2n-3m-1/69256)

Comment: Catalan's conjecture (now proven!) states that the only perfect powers with difference $1$ are $8$ and $9$.

Comment: @Peter But you don't need that. See the reference supplied by lulu.

Comment: @almagest Yes, but  the question does not explicitely demand a solution without it.

Comment: @Peter Why use a sledge-hammer (only proved in 2002) to crack a nut!